# Custom button classes in django crispy forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

The technical issue of styling buttons in django crispy forms. I would like to apply my own class, without using the primary button class.

```
class MyForm(Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fields("field_1"),
            Fields("field_2"),
            Submit('submit', u'On', css_class='own-css-class'),
        )
```

Basically, I solved this by adding `self.helper.form_tag = False` and inserting the button code directly into the html template. In addition, I deleted the submit button from the layout.

```
class MyForm(Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fields("field_1"),
            Fields("field_2"),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
```

Is this solution correct and will it be compatible in the long term?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you create your own custom button and use that when creating your `layout`.

```py
class CustomButton(BaseInput)
    input_type = 'submit'
    field_classes = 'my custom css'
```

Comment: I haven't checked it, but... In retrospect, I haven't noticed any troubles with setting the flag to false.